# Stuck on an C exercise: Arrays and Strings

Tags: c

(Preface: I am not a programmer, at all, but I'm studying it so I can build some understanding of how it works, so please bear with my ignorance!)

I've been working away on the C language tutorials over at c.learncodethehardway.org.  Made it about 8 exercises in, when I got stuck on the 9th.  Here's the link:

http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex9.html

I pretty much have a grasp on all of this, except when it gets to the author's breakdown in the "What You Should See" section.  Here's a copy/paste of the code in question:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int numbers[4] = {0};
char name[4] = {'a'};

// first, print them out raw
printf("numbers: %d %d %d %d\n",
        numbers[0], numbers[1],
        numbers[2], numbers[3]);

printf("name each: %c %c %c %c\n",
        name[0], name[1],
        name[2], name[3]);
printf("name: %s\n", name);

// setup the numbers
numbers[0] = 1;
numbers[1] = 2;
numbers[2] = 3;
numbers[3] = 4;

// setup the name
name[0] = 'Z';
name[1] = 'e';
name[2] = 'd';
name[3] = '\0';

// then print them out initialized
printf("numbers: %d %d %d %d\n",
        numbers[0], numbers[1],
        numbers[2], numbers[3]);

printf("name each: %c %c %c %c\n",
        name[0], name[1],
        name[2], name[3]);

// print the name like a string
printf("name: %s\n", name);

// another way to use name
char *another = "Zed";

printf("another: %s\n", another);

printf("another each: %c %c %c %c\n",
        another[0], another[1],
        another[2], another[3]);

return 0;
}
```

What the program will print on screen looks like this:

```
numbers: 0 0 0 0
name each: a   
name: a
numbers: 1 2 3 4
name each: Z e d 
name: Zed
another: Zed
another each: Z e d
$
```

Now what confuses me in this tutorial is this statement by the author:

**"When each element of name is printed, only the first element 'a' shows up because the '\0' character is special and won't display."**

I find that strange, since I define name as 'a' up top, but I never call out a '\0' character until *after* I print the name variable for a second time.

Why didn't it print with just 'a a a a', the same way numbers printed out '0 0 0 0'?  Is it something to do with the ' ' around the a?

Comment: with all compiler warnings enabled, this line: 'int main(int argc, char *argv[])' will cause the compiler to output two warnings about unused parameters.

Comment: Try `printf("numbers: %d %d %d %d\n", name[0], name[1], name[2], name[3]);`  --> "numbers: 97 0 0 0"

Answer (score 5):

> Why didn't it print with just 'a a a a', the same way numbers printed
>   out '0 0 0 0'?

Because any array values (in an initialized array) that are not given explicit initializers get default-initialized to zero.  ('\0' is just another way of specifying the NUL/zero value as a byte)

> Is it something to do with the ' ' around the a?

No, it's just that

```
char name[4] = {'a'};
```

is logically equivalent to:

```
char name[4] = {'a', 0, 0, 0};
```

which is also logically equivalent to:

```
char name[4] = {'a', '\0', '\0', '\0'};
```

Note that any C-string compatible function (including printf()) will recognize a zero-byte as indicating the end of the string and will stop reading the string when it encounters the zero-byte.  That is why only "a" is printed.

Comment: OK, just so I know I'm understanding this completely: int numbers[4] = {0}; will print out 0,0,0,0 because it's an "int" variable, and knows that the [4] is the amount of {0} in the array.  char name[4] = {'a'}; will print out 'a' because it's a "char" variable, which, if not given explicit descriptions of the contents of the array beyond the single character provided, will fill the remaining contents of said array with "0".  (Did I get that right?)

Comment: Both 'numbers' and 'name' are arrays.  The 'numbers' array contains four int variables, while the 'name' array contains for 'char' variables.  Since a char array is a sequence of chars, it can also be interpreted as a c-string (which is a sequence of chars with a NUL terminator byte at the end).  When you pass %s to printf() you are telling it or interpret the associated argument as a c-string; when you pass %c to printf() you are telling it to interpret the associated argument as a char.

Comment: But yes, if you provide fewer explicit values in your array-initializer than there are items in the array, then the remaining (non-explicitly-initialized) array slots will be implicitly initialized to the value 0 (which in the 'name' case happily corresponds to the value used as a NUL-terminator according to the C-string conventions)

Answer (score 1):

Unspecified array values are automatically initialized with integer 0 by most C compilers. This not only occurs for integer arrays, but for character arrays as well.

Now, the character literal `\0` has the value 0. And in C, character values are stored as their ASCII values. So when the compiler appends 0s to the rest of the character array, they're treated as `\0` literals or null, which is also used to mark the end of the string.

As proof, In your example, if you replace the print statement for individual character array elements with,

```
printf("name each: %c %d %d %d\n",name[0], name[1], name[2], name[3]);
```

You will find that it prints:

```
name each: a 0 0 0
```

This is because we have used the `%d` format specifier which is for integer values instead of the `%c` format specifier which expects a character value. And since the integer value zero is same as `\0`, the string terminates.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you use something like:

```
char name[4] = {'a'};
```

**name[0] = a** and the rest has nothing (as '\0' only), and by the rest I mean name[1], name[2], ...

Comment: you might want to add: nothing here is 0 which is equal to '\0'.

Answer (score 0):

Why learn C the "hard way" when you can learn it the easy way by reading the book known as K&R C, 2nd Edition.